# Inconsistent accessibility when everything is public

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to Deserialize a JSON response from Google Maps Geocode.

Those are the classes I coded based on the response.

```
public class GoogleGeoCodeResponse
    {
        public string status { get; set; }
        public results[] results { get; set; }
    }

public class results
    {
        public address_component[] address_components { get; set; }
        public String formatted_address { get; set; }
        public Geometry geometry { get; set; }
        public Boolean partial_match { get; set; }
        public string[] types { get; set; }
    }

public class address_component
    {
        public String long_name { get; set; }
        public String short_name { get; set; }
        public String[] types { get; set; }
    }

public class Geometry
    {
        public bounds_viewport bounds { get; set; }
        public LatLong location { get; set; }
        public String location_type { get; set; }
    }

public class bounds_viewport
    {
        public LatLong northeast { get; set; }
        public LatLong southwest { get; set; }
    }

public class LatLong
    {
        public double lon { get; set; }
        public double lat { get; set; }
    }
```

On my form button click I use this code.

```
var json = new WebClient().DownloadString("url");
GoogleGeoCodeResponse test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GoogleGeoCodeResponse>(json);

MessageBox.Show(test.results[0].geometry.location.lat + " / " + test.results[0].geometry.location.lon);
```

Then I wanted to see if I get the correct information but I'm getting:

"Error  1 Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'WindowsFormsApplication1.results[]' is less accessible than property 'WindowsFormsApplication1.GoogleGeoCodeResponse.results'"

I've looked a bunch of post with the same problem but they always had something private or internal somewhere that would lead to this error. As you can see everything I declared is public.

I don't understand why something public inside of a class would be more accessible than the class itself.

I am fairly new to C# and JSON so this might be something really simple.

Comment: Are these nested classes at all? (Are they declared within another class?)

Comment: I've tried inside of my form classe and outside of it and it did not changed anything. Would I need to make a brand new class and add the code in it ?

Comment: I realise I did not really answer your question but yes they are inside my form's class.

Comment: Is the error visible in the watch window? If so, you seem to have put `results` variable with a scope set to `WindowsFormsApplication1` in the watch.

Comment: And is your *form* declared public? If it's declared as `internal` (which is the default) then any public classes within it would also have an *effective* visibility of `internal`.

Comment: This is only visible in the Error List window. The 'results' variable is only declared in the 'GoogleGeoCodeResponse', I don't even know if I could acces 'results[]' directly through 'WindowsFormsApplication1'.

PS: I do not have access to the watch window since I can't compile.

Comment: @JonSkeet my form is declare public partial, I removed partial and still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I took all of my class and put the code out of my form's class and it worked. I put it back in the class and it still worked I don't know what I have changed, maybe it was just bugged or something anyway thanks for the help!